# How to lock two forms together and moving them as a single one?

Tags: vb.net, user-controls, runtime

I'm creating a form at Run Time and a control is added to it. I'm choosing to locate the form2 close to form1  with `New Point(Form1.Location.X + Form1.Width, Form1.Location.Y)`and both form border style are set on "None", so I'm using 3 Mouse events in order to make them "draggable" (both in form1 and form2). I'm using a good code from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64201041/2497570)

And everything works fine. So issues start when form2 is open.
I created a gif [Imgur gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raDJ4.jpg) in order to explain better .
Form 1 alone id movable, form2 alone is movable.
Form2 moves form1 without moving itself.
The code I'm using in form1(usercontrol1) to  call form2(qrcode):

```
    Dim qrForm = New SchermataCode()

    qrForm.ShowForm()
    Form1.TopMost = True
    qrform.dispose()
```

What I'm using in the  control2(qrcode):

```
    Private Sub qrcode_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseDown
    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
        startPosition = e.Location
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub qrcode_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseMove
    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
        Form1.Location = New Point(
            Form1.Left + (e.X - startPosition.X),
            Form1.Top + (e.Y - startPosition.Y))
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub PictureBox10_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox10.MouseMove
    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
        Form1.Location = New Point(
            Form1.Left + (e.X - startPosition.X),
            Form1.Top + (e.Y - startPosition.Y))
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox10_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox10.MouseDown
    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
        startPosition = e.Location
    End If
End Sub
```

This is how I'm generating a new form and adding control2 (qrcode)

```
    Option Strict On

Public Class SchermataCode
    Implements IDisposable

    Private qrForm As Form = Nothing
    Private qr As qrcode = Nothing
    Private startPosition As Point = Point.Empty
    ' Dim qrcode As New qrcode
    Public Sub New()
        qrForm = New Form() With {
            .FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None,
            .StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual,
            .Location = New Point(Form1.Location.X + Form1.Width, Form1.Location.Y),
            .AutoScaleMode = AutoScaleMode.None,
            .Icon = DirectCast(My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("_" & My.Settings.icona), Icon),
            .Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
            .TopMost = True
        }

        qr = New qrcode()
        AddHandler qr.MouseDown, AddressOf qrCode_MouseDown
        AddHandler qr.MouseMove, AddressOf qrCode_MouseMove
        AddHandler qr.DoubleClick, AddressOf qrCode_OnDoubleClick
        qrForm.Controls.Add(qr)
    End Sub

    Public Function ShowForm() As Image
        qrForm.ClientSize = qr.Size
        qrForm.Showdialog
        Form1.TopMost = True
    End Function


    Private Sub qrCode_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs)
        If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
            startPosition = e.Location
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub qrCode_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs)
        If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
            qrForm.Location = New Point(
                qrForm.Left + (e.X - startPosition.X),
                qrForm.Top + (e.Y - startPosition.Y))
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub qrCode_OnDoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        qrForm.Close()
    End Sub

    Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
        Dispose(True)
        GC.SuppressFinalize(Me)
    End Sub

    Protected Overridable Sub Dispose(disposing As Boolean)
        If disposing Then
            If qrForm IsNot Nothing Then
                RemoveHandler qr.DoubleClick, AddressOf qrCode_OnDoubleClick
                RemoveHandler qr.MouseDown, AddressOf qrCode_MouseDown
                RemoveHandler qr.MouseMove, AddressOf qrCode_MouseMove
            End If
            qr?.Dispose()
            qrForm?.Dispose()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Anyone has any idea? I'm looking to open form2 close to form1, drag both together and If form2 is Double clicked then close it and leave just form1 open. Form1 doesn't drag form2 when together.

Thanks

Comment: You can't interact with the main form because in the `ShowForm()` function you're displaying "qrForm" via `ShowDialog()`.  This causes code to STOP until that form is dismissed.  The easy solution would be to switch to `Show()`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried also with show and it does the samething. I probably forgot to write again .show() before to post the question

Comment: Then the problem isn't in the code you've shown us.  If you `Show()` the second form then you'll still get the events firing in the first form.  If you `ShowDialog()` the second form then events in the first form will STOP.   I'm willing to bet you've got another `ShowDialog()` somewhere...SEARCH for it.

Comment: Hi, I double check even If I was already sure, there is no other call to form2. Anyway, even if it was present another showdialog, how can we explain the form1 moving in such a crazy way like i shown in the gif?

Comment: "how can we explain the form1 moving in such a crazy way like i shown in the gif?"   ???  In your second code snippet, in `qrcode_MouseMove(...)` you are explicitly moving Form1: `Form1.Location = New Point(Form1.Left + (e.X - startPosition.X), Form1.Top + (e.Y - startPosition.Y))`.  That explains the "crazy way".  If you truly do not have another `ShowDialog()`, then somehow you are preventing Form1 from handling it's events normally.  Did you by chance DISABLE Form1 somewhere in your code?  `Form1.Enabled = False`?

Comment: You should probably update the posted code with what you REALLY have.  If you truly changed the `ShowDialog()` to `Show()`, then your "qr" form would display and then immediately disappear.  This is because you call `ShowForm()` and then two lines later you issue `qrform.dispose()`.  Based on your current posting, all we can do is GUESS what the problem might be as the code and your description don't match the symptoms.

Comment: Hi @Idle_Mind, thanks for your answers!! 
So, Thinking logically, I'm using 2 events twice! Once in qrcode control and once while generating qrform. I just removed those from qrcode control and in picturebox10Mouse_Move  and like this I'm avoiding that crazy moving. 
Now, qrform is dragging correctly form1, but form1 is not dragging qrform. Why? Because while I created a new point to form1 in qrcode(in Schermatacode) Mouse_move(the same location of qrform), I  didn't say to form1(usercontrol1) Mouse_move  event to move qrform.

Comment: So my question is: 
I can't declare again "Dim qrForm = New SchermataCode()" in form1(usercontrol)Mouse_move as I'm already calling it In a button , so how can I make it public ? I tried to insert that under Public Class UserControl1 but it goes on StackOverflow.. Thanks

Comment: To make it clear, What should I declare in order to write something like this under usercontrol Mouse move: 
        `If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
            Form1.Location = New Point(
                Form1.Left + (e.X - startPosition.X),
                Form1.Top + (e.Y - startPosition.Y))
            qrForm.Location = New Point(
                qrForm.Left + (e.X - startPosition.X),
                qrForm.Top + (e.Y - startPosition.Y))
        End If`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone reading this question/answer, a lot was done via CHAT, and this was not the final solution.

> So my question is: I can't declare again "Dim qrForm = New
> SchermataCode()" in form1(usercontrol)Mouse_move as I'm already
> calling it In a button , so how can I make it public ? I tried to
> insert that under Public Class UserControl1 but it goes on
> StackOverflow.. Thanks

This is a design issue involving [Scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/declared-elements/scope).

Move the declaration of "qrForm" to UserControl level, so it is not in the Button handler:

```
' ... code in UserControl (that is housed by the Main Form) ...

Private qrForm As SchermataCode

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If IsNothing(qrForm) Then
        qrForm = New SchermataCode()
    End If
    qrForm.ShowForm()
    Form1.TopMost = True
End Sub
```

Not that I'm checking to see if "qrForm" is nothing (null) or if it has been disposed (closed) before creating it.

In your handlers where you you want to move that secondary form, you'd do something similar before attempting to use it:

```
' ... code in UserControl (that is housed by the Main Form) ...

' The Foo() below could be any handler (like a MouseMove)
Private Sub Foo() 
    If (Not IsNothing(qrForm)) AndAlso (Not qrForm.IsDisposed) Then

        ' ... do something with "qrForm" in here (like move it) ...

    End If
End Sub
```

**----- After watching the GIF posted at the bottom of the comments -----**

Good grief...I see what is happening now.  **Your variable names leave much to be desired.**  In UserControl1, you have a variable called `qrForm` of type `SchermataCode`.  Then, inside class `SchermataCode`, you have ANOTHER variable called `qrForm` which is the actual form that you want to manipulate!  We are SO CLOSE!

First, in class `SchermataCode`, change the declaration of `qrForm` from `Private` to `Public`:

```
Public Class SchermataCode
    Implements IDisposable

    Public qrForm As Form = Nothing

    ' ... the rest of the existing code ...

End Class
```

Now, over in `UserControl1`, we want to access that "inner" `qrForm` above.  This will look weird because you named the variables the same:

```
' ... inside the PictureBox5_MouseMove() method of UserControl1 ...

If Not IsNothing(qrForm) Then   
   ' Let's make a variable that points directly to the secondary Form:
    Dim frm As Form = qrForm.qrForm ' <--- use better names next time!  =)

    ' Now let's move it:
    frm.Location = New Point(
        frm.Left + (e.X - startPosition.X),
        frm.Top + (e.Y - startPosition.Y))
End If
```

Hope that solves the issue now.

Comment: I already tried to declare it under Main Form public class, it goes on stackoverflow. 
What You mean with moving it to form level? The main form code is basically empty, Because I'm adding a user control at load event. 
So, trying to declare it under public class Usercontrol1, it gives back an error as IsDispose is not member of SchermataCode

Comment: No...you are confusing the two forms.  This code is in the FIRST form where you click a button to show the SECOND form.  In the GIF, you clearly click a button in the first form to show a second form.  Of course you wouldn't declare a new SchermataCode, in class SchermataCode; that would be a problem.  It sounds to me like  you do not have a clear grasp of how your own code works...

Comment: Probably I explained it wrongly. So, the Main Form is = form 1 which contain the User Control1. A button in User control is creating qrForm which contain qrcode Control. So both forms contains controls! In both your codes  I can see "code in main form..." which makes me think about Usercontrol1, So here it comes the answer of before, I specified I was declaring it under public class Usercontrol1(so not in SchermataCode as You are stating) and i get that error.

Comment: Instead if I declare Dim qrForm = New SchermataCode() i get no errors but it goes in stackoverflow at RunTime.
Is there a way to declare qrform usable in usercontrol1? I'm pretty sure that this would work under Usercontrol1 Mouse_Move event if just I'm able to declare it..`If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then   Form1.Location = New Point(                 Form1.Left + (e.X - startPosition.X),     Form1.Top + (e.Y - startPosition.Y))             qrForm.Location = New Point( qrForm.Left + (e.X - startPosition.X),                 qrForm.Top + (e.Y - startPosition.Y))    End If`

Comment: Like this, I'm doing  same of what I wrote in the qrform Mouse_move handlers(during qrform creation, so Schermatacode class). 
That's why qrform is moving form1(usercontrol1) but this lastone is not moving qrform

Comment: Gotcha!  This was not clear from the original post.  You have UserControl1 in Form1, and it's the UserControl that is creating the secondary Form.   ...BUT you want code in Form1 (not UserControl1) to move the secondary Form (to which it does not have a reference).  So my question would be, WHY is a UserControl being used here in the first place?  You only have one of instance of that UserControl on the main form.  Also, since the secondary form is moving Form1, it's of little value being re-used from somewhere else.  Your overall design is very confusing from a coding standpoint...

Comment: One way to "fix" this is to do exactly what I said, but in the UserControl.  Move the "qrForm" out of the Button click handler and into the main UserControl class, BUT change it's declaration from `Private` to `Public`.  Now, in the main Form, you can use something like `UserControl1.qrForm` to access it.  You'd still need to do those checks like I demonstrated to make sure you aren't trying to manipulate a secondary form that doesn't yet exist.

Comment: So to answer your questions: I'm using a usercontrol that I can dispose after I use it in order to save memory. Actually, this is the first time I'm usin controls instead of forms and I'm trying to make it light as possible. The user control is occuping all the surface of the form, so in this case I need to play with usercontrole events instead of form1 events. I already try to make form1 instead of usercontrol1 draggable and it doesn't work as there is no area of form1 selectable.

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understand your second answer. Why are you still calling it "main form"? main form or form 1 contains already Usercontrol1 as I explained, which contain 0 code. All the code in order to make it movable is in Usercontrol Mouse_move event.

Comment: "The user control is occupying all the surface of the form"  So is the UserControl going to be swapped out for a different one?...so you can switch what is being displayed in the Form?  My previous comment will need to be modified, sorry.

Comment: No usercontrol is not going to be swapped out for a different one. Endeed I'm creating a new form (qrform) at Runtime in order to contain qrcode control. I think that a gif would explain better than words in this case . Look here [link](https://imgur.com/a/JIRn9Nf)

Comment: See edited code at the bottom of the main post above.

Comment: Thanks for your Edit. 
So, the variable in usercontrol1 I just added in order to try everything ahah.. So, the only variable in there is  in Schermata Code. 
unfortunately your edit still don't work.. Have a look please [link](https://imgur.com/a/XvFnQdN)

Comment: Apologies...I made a couple of rapid fire EDITS while you were apparently implementing my first suggestion.  Look closely again at the code at the bottom of my post as that code is different than what you have.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your help, but I took the right code before, I double check again now and I can confirm I'm using your last  code. The proof:  [link](https://imgur.com/a/7wo5mQN)
p.s. I changed  qrForm from Private to Public as you said too.
P.s.2 I can just see 1 edit 29 minutes ago.. the second might be lost?

Comment: It's the `qrForm` inside class `SchermataCode` that needs to be `Public` (not the one inside `UserControl1` that you just showed).  Also, in `UserControl1`, don't use the `New` keyword for `qrForm` there, as you don't want to create it until the user clicks that Button to display it.  Can we see that Button code to make you don't have a `LOCAL` variable hiding the UserControl variable?

Comment: Sorry i didn't show you in the gif, but i wrote it.. I set already qr form to public in SchermataCode. I also shown you what happen when that declaration in User control1 is being commented. I get two errors.  I know that code is not supposed to be in User control 1, but then I get the errors you can see in the gif. Again I repeat, I already set qrform on public in Schermatacode. I hope not to bother you showing you another gif. [link](https://imgur.com/a/rAyHBo2)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222741/discussion-between-idle-mind-and-mattia).